# chmod: cannot access '/home/alpine/*.sh': Permission denied

Tags: docker, chmod

i have try to running my java application, and my apps run an docker image and build it. but when i run and try until all of done. i got error like this : this docker run on windows 10 operating system

```
[INFO] + chmod 0755 '/home/alpine/*.sh'
[INFO]
[INFO] chmod: cannot access '/home/alpine/*.sh': Permission denied
[INFO]
[ERROR] The command '/bin/sh -c set -ex   && chmod 0755 /home/alpine/*.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:42 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-16T16:16:11+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.10:build (default) on project oracle-admin: Could not build image: The command '/bin/sh -c set -ex   && chmod 0755 /home/alpine/*.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

but i don't know what is exactly problem and how to fix it ? here my dockerfile format

```
FROM cirepo/service-base-image-java:openjdk-11.0.2-en_US.UTF-8_Asia

ARG ARTIFACT_REPOSITORY=unknown
ARG BUILD_TIMESTAMP=unknown
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY=unknown
ARG GIT_BRANCH=unknown
ARG GIT_COMMIT_ID=unknown
ARG GIT_COMMIT_ID_ABBREV=unknown
ARG GIT_COMMIT_TIME=unknown
ARG GIT_REMOTE_ORIGIN_URL=unknown
ARG JAR_FILE
ARG PROJECT_ARTIFACTID=unknown
ARG PROJECT_GROUPID=unknown
ARG PROJECT_VERSION=unknown

LABEL image.artifact.repository=$ARTIFACT_REPOSITORY
LABEL image.build.timestamp=$BUILD_TIMESTAMP
LABEL image.docker.registry=$DOCKER_REGISTRY
LABEL image.git.branch=$GIT_BRANCH
LABEL image.git.commit.id=$GIT_COMMIT_ID
LABEL image.git.commit.id.abbrev=$GIT_COMMIT_ID_ABBREV
LABEL image.git.commit.time=$GIT_COMMIT_TIME
LABEL image.git.remote.origin.url=$GIT_REMOTE_ORIGIN_URL
LABEL image.project.artifactId=$PROJECT_ARTIFACTID
LABEL image.project.groupId=$PROJECT_GROUPID
LABEL image.project.version=$PROJECT_VERSION

COPY --chown=alpine:alpine src/main/docker /
COPY --chown=alpine:alpine target/${JAR_FILE} /home/alpine
RUN set -ex \
  && chmod 0755 /home/alpine/*.sh
```

my question is how to fix this issue ?

when i see in my docker application are ready in docker with name none. here the apps

[image]

but when i click run i cannot run this apps.... my question is what is problem exactly about permission denied when read dockerfile, and then how to run application in docker image ?

Comment: This is about `chmod`, which is a system utility, not Java, which is a programming language. Off topic.

Comment: @user207421 he is a newcomer

Comment: i am newcomer using docker.... it is run my dockerfile from java maven.... so i need how to fix this issue when running dockerfile in windows....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding on Dockerfile

after `COPY --chown=alpine:alpine target/${JAR_FILE} /home/alpine`

:`USER alpine` or `USER root`

Comment: still cannot run